# Terraform: Looking for a simpler way to get a corresponding value in list of maps

Tags: terraform

Say I have the following list of maps in a variable:

```
locals {
  list = [{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}, {a = 4, b = 5, c = 6}]
}
```

I have a value for a, and I need to get the map that corresponds to that value, but get another value from that map I am doing the following:

```
output "b" {
  value = [ for y in local.list: y.b if y.a == 4 ]
}
```

So in the above example if I put a == 4, I get back the value of 5. If a == 1, I get 2.... except I get it back as an array so I access just index 0 to get my value(in my use case there will never be matching values or more than a single value returned)

```
value = ([ for y in local.list: y.b if y.a == 4 ])[0]
```

This works completely as intended, but I just can't tell if this is how I should be accomplishing this or if there is a function I'm missing that will do it cleaner.  In my code I am ending up having 3 nested for loops in a line to get corresponding values and it just seems dirty for lack of a better word.

My actual use case if anyone cares if for AWS routes.  The lookup loops look like: public subnet ID > public AZ. Public AZ > firewall subnet ID.  firewall subnet ID > VPC endpoint.  All so I can take my public subnet route and tie it to the VPC endpoint that lives in the same AZ(and there is an extra step cause my firewall object doesn't have an AZ as a value, only subnet ID and VPCE ID's)

Comment: that code looks fine to me ...

Comment: maybe you could use `one` instead of returning the first element, so `one([ for y in local.list: y.b if y.a == 4 ])`. It seems to fit your use case (docs [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one)).